# Android - bitmap operations, keep source bitmap or use second bitmap and recycle source

Tags: android, bitmap, recycle

One would think that the second approach would be more efficient but I can't say that I see any improvement using it. Is there a difference between the following two ? (memmory wise ofcourse)

```
Bitmap bm=MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
bm=cropAndScaleBitmap(bm);
//use bm
```

vs

```
Bitmap bm=MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
Bitmap b =cropAndScaleBitmap(bm);
bm.recycle();
//use b
```

Answer (score 0):

Things to note here ...

> Even though you have specified recycle, it will have any effect only
>   when the next GC is trigerred.

Other things to note

1. In pre-Honeycomb versions of Android the memory for bitmaps was (is) allocated from unmanaged memory.It will take at least 2 passes of GC to collect it. Another thing is - it is really difficult to trace - DDMS does not see it and neither does MAT.
2. Read this link https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html. If api level >10,I don't think we need to call recycle.

Refer to this link ... It provides all details and the code sample for how to implement step by step.

https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example (first one)  you don't actually reuse the source, you just overwrite the value of the `bm` making it point to the new bitmap instead, in this case you can no longer call `recycle` on the source bitmap as you no longer have a reference to it.

I recommend using the second method to make sure the source bitmap is recycled.